# Parallel execution using Selenium grid and test suites

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm working on Selenium and I currently have a hub connected to two vms running linux with all the browsers.

I was able to launch the browsers . However, event hough I have two vms all my tests run on a single browser on a single vm. Selenium does not launch more than one browser in a vm. I have set maximum instance to 5 and it reflects in my gris console. I have testsuite which needs to run on linux and windows vm and it has to run simultaneously . Im using the WebDriver to call my grid like this .

```
 capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
           capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
           driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://XXX.XXX.XXX.:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

And this is how I create my test Suite:

```
testNames.add(SupportPortalTestSuite.class.getName());
        JUnitCore.main(testNames.toArray(new String[testNames.size()]));
```

Also when I register my nodes I get:

```
11:28:47.403 INFO - using the json request : {"class":"org.openqa.grid.common.RegistrationRequest","capabilities":[{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*googlechrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"Selenium","browserName":"*iexplore","maxInstances":1},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"firefox","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"LINUX","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"chrome","maxInstances":5},{"platform":"WINDOWS","seleniumProtocol":"WebDriver","browserName":"internet explorer","maxInstances":1}],"configuration":{"port":5555,"register":true,"host":"10.235.132.161","proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy","maxSession":5,"hubHost":"10.235.1.50","role":"node","registerCycle":5000,"hub":"http://10.235.1.50:4444/grid/register","hubPort":4444,"url":"http://10.235.132.161:5555","remoteHost":"http://10.235.132.161:5555"}}
11:28:47.407 INFO - starting auto register thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
```

I need to run the tests on all available browsers on the vms simultaneously .

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Grid give you the ability to run tests in parallel but doesn't handle it automatically. This is typically done with a test runner that handles it for you. Some frameworks like TestNG have this built-in but would likely need some customizing depending on your code.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is preferred to use some frameworks such as testNG, you can run them with a plain java Threaded way too.